# Using mutate ifelse and rollappy to create a conditional factor based on changes in continuous variable

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, zoo, data-wrangling

tl;dr I need to condition if a promotion was on or not based upon drops(or not) in price over time. I am open to alternative approaches.

I have a data frame of prices split across several grouping factors over time. My goal is for each 'ITEM' in 'EACH' store to check the mode of the 'PRICE' for the past 7 dates (if they exist). If the value of the observation is less than 10% of the mode of price, then in the 'Promotion' column should be populated with a 1, if not a 0.

**EXAMPLE DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(Date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 10),
              Item = rep(LETTERS[1:4], times = 10),
              Store =  as.factor(sample(rep(c("NY","SYD","LON","PAR"), each = 10))),
              Price = rnorm(n = 40, mean = 2.5, sd = 1))
```

So far I have used dplyr's `group_split` to break out item and store groupings into separate data frames to capture all the conditions. What I believe I need to do now is `mutate` the new column using an `ifelse` statement with `rollapply`. I have so far attempted to use the following line of code...

```
data %>% mutate(Promotion = ifelse(rollapply(Price, 7, Mode <= Price*0.91,1,0)))
```

this returns an error statement...

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `PRMT_IND2`.
x comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types
i Input `PRMT_IND2` is `ifelse(...)`.
```

I am not really sure where to go from here. If you have time I would also appreciate it if you could tell me how to apply this across all the groups created by the group_split, and how to stitch this back together.

*note.* Observations (dates/rows) are no even across shops, and some are populated with less than 7 days.  I can remove these if the rolling apply will not work without it. But that loses quite a chunk of data.

I am using this function for the Mode...

```
  Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to calculate Mode? The function which you are using returns most number of time a value occurs in a vector. For example, `x <- c(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1)` would return Mode as 1 because it occurs 3 times. `Price` in your dataset is a numeric value and it is highly unlikely that any number would occur multiple times so I think `Mode` is not the right function.

Comment: @RonakShah I can see your point and would agree but the price varies little within each store when not on promotion changes by more than >= 10% only occur when promotions are on. I omitted the original promotion indicator from example, but used it for filtering in the data am am using. The original indicator is occasionally incorrect, and it is this that I am looking to change when no promotion is signalled(== 0).  Is there a better approach that comes to mind? Should I add the promotion indicator to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use rolling mean instead of mode.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dat %>%
   group_by(Item, Store) %>%
   mutate(Promotion = as.integer(abs((Price - 
                         rollmeanr(Price, 7, fill = NA))/Price) > 0.1))
```

This will give `NA`'s to first 6 value and give 1 if `Price` varies more than 10% than previous 7 days value and 0 otherwise. Also note, that we take absolute value here so it will give 1 if the price increases by 10% or decreases.

Answer (score 1):

As Ronah Shak pointed out, the function does not seem like the most appropriate choice.
Also, note that the use of tabulate converts the values to integers, which may be problematic for the values you have.

Regarding the error, as you correctly guessed, the problem was that your splitted data does not always have 7 dates so the `rollapply` function with `width=7`returned an error.
Allowing your function to use the length of the Date vector OR 7 if available solves the issue.
Also, you can use just apply your function using `group_by`, splitting the data is not necessary.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Store,Item)%>%
  mutate(price_check = Price*0.91, 
         Promotion = ifelse(rollapply(Price, width = min(length(Date),7), Mode)>=price_check,1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a better way to implement the mode to avoid the integer? I'm thinking to perhaps use diff between the mean window value and the observation with a maximal -9% tolerance? btw I have already filtered promoted values this is to check errors when price drops were not recorded, hence lack of value change. BTW I also changed the conditon to <= Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: rollapplyr can handle the case where the data is shorter than the width. It does not return an error.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thank you, I hadn't thought to use that function.